# Can a surge in buying due to a recent drop artificially raise the price without actually fixing the underlying problem?

Tags: united-states, stocks

Assume you were omniscient and knew the primary reason for a dip in the market. Is the following mechanism for a temporary rise, post dip, feasible? Reason X causes a dip. Investors, not fully aware of the full potential of reason X, rush to buy on the low, as they see stocks are at a discount. This surge in buys leads to a raising of the stock price, even as underlying reason X doesn't go away/gets worse.  Is that sort of 'quick the market is down, lets buy' reaction capable of raising the stock price all on its own, even sans an improvement of reason X?

Edit: I made this question more general and less specific about a current situation.

Comment: Every trading day the market zigzags up and down regardless of whether it's a large move up or down because it's an auction.  While it's much more of a macro example, in 2008 the DJIA dropped from about 14,000 to 6,500 and yet within that drop there were a few days where it was up over a 1,000 points, a few days up over 500 points and dozens of days when it was up over 200 points.  The market isn't linear intraday or long term.

Comment: How do you know the why?  Your first sentence is a bold statement that is probably not true.  Timing the market is a fools game.

Comment: @BobBaerker It seems to me that Pete actually means the OP's first sentence, as I don't see you mentioned in his comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that sort of 'quick the market is down, lets buy' reaction capable of raising the stock price all on its own, even sans an improvement of reason X?

Sure - but the real question is - which one is right? Is the original dip an overreaction based on one variable, and the bounce is valid? Or is the cause of the dip still valid and the bounce due to opportunism will be short-lived (called a "dead-cat bounce" in the technical world)? Or are there hundreds of other variables that determine stock price (not all of which are rational), so trying to attribute all price movements to one or two is naive?

Comment: i think you hit on the key point - when the underlying problem hasn't gone away, the "buy on the dip" mentality leads to the so-called "dead cat bounce" which will be corrected by a subsequent reversion to the lower price.

Comment: That is often referred to as "Don't try to catch a falling knife"